# Transform XML to XML with XSLT and xsl: for-each

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach, xslt-1.0

I want to create a metadata-XML-file from another XML-file with XSLT.
The **input**-xml looks something like this:

```
<TEI>
<teiHeader>
<fileDesc>
<titleStmt>
   <author>
        <persName>
             <surname>Doe</surname>
             <forename>Jane</forename>
        </persName>
        <affiliation>UniversityA</affiliation>
   </author>
   <author>
        <persName>
             <surname>Smith</surname>
             <forename>John</forename>
        </persName>
        <affiliation>UniversityB</affiliation>
   </author>
</titleStmt>
</fileDesc>
</teiHeader>
</TEI>
```

The **output**-metadata-file I want to create should look like this:

```
<metadata>
  <creators>
    <creator>
      <name>Doe, Jane</name>
      <affiliation>UniversityA</affiliation>
    </creator>
    <creator>
      <name>Smith, Jon</name>
      <affiliation>UniversityB</affiliation>
    </creator>
  </creators>
</metadata>
```

I used an **XSLT** stylesheet like this:

```
<creators><xsl:for-each select="TEI/teiHeader/fileDesc/titleStmt/author">
      <creator>
          <name><xsl:value-of select="//surname"/>, <xsl:value-of select="//forename"/></name>
          <affiliation><xsl:value-of select="//affiliation"/></affiliation>
      </creator></xsl:for-each>
</creators>
```

But the **output** keeps looking like this:

```
<metadata>
<creators>
      <creator>
         <name>Doe, Jane</name>
         <affiliation>UniversityA</affiliation>
      </creator>
      <creator>
         <name>Doe, Jane</name>
         <affiliation>UniversityA</affiliation>
      </creator>
</creators>
</metadata>
```

**So my question is:** How can I loop through the input-xml and collect every author's name and affiliation in an individual creator-element?

Comment: Replace //surname by persName/surname. When you are in your for-each you are in the context of <author>, by using // you go back to the top of your input document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//surname"/>
```

selects **all** `surname` elements in the entire document and returns the value of the first one, regardless of your current context.

To select the `surname` element that is a descendant of the current `author` you need to do:

```
<xsl:value-of select=".//surname"/>
```

or - preferably - use the full relative path:

```
<xsl:value-of select="persName/surname"/>
```

Likewise for the other elements.